# Creating a questionnaire to show curated content on wix velo site

Tags: velo

Trying to create an entrance questionnaire for my guitar lessons site by layering normal boxes with buttons and text using show() & hide() functions in velo. But the NeverPlayed click event seems to be malfunctioning without showing an error.  Below is the code and the preview link for reference.

```
$w.onReady(function () {
  
    $w('#box1').hide()
});

export function image3_click(event) {
    
    // This is to keep the show box1 on clicking electric guitar's img: 
    $w('#box1').show();

}

export function NeverPlayed(event) {
    // This function is to hide box1 on clicking neverplayed button and showing next question box with text
    
    $w('#box1').hide()
    $w('#box2').show()
    $w('#text12').show()
}


export function few_months(event) {
    // This function is to hide box1 on clicking few months button and showing next question box with text
    $w('#box1').hide()
    $w('#box3').show()
    $w('#text13').show()
}
```

Preview Link -  https://shredbaseofficial.wixsite.com/my-site

Answer (score 0):

The code in the function looks okay. Are you sure you've wired it correctly in the Properties & Events panel. Have you tried adding a `console.log('anything');` to the beginning of the `NeverPlayed()` function to make sure it is running?

Comment: Problem is with the few_months() function. I added console.log('anything'); as per your suggestion and it logged but the rest of the code still didn't execute. It executes after ones i have triggered never_played() function but i don't want that.

Comment: It's a little hard to follow what's going on here without seeing the elements on the page, but from playing around, I would get that your box3 and text13 are inside your box2. So when you show box2 and text13, if box2 is still hidden, you won't see them.

Comment: all boxes are seperate. Yet the code executes as if box3 is inside box2. That's exactly what the issue is. I guess it's something that needs to be fixed by wix from their end. But they don't have customer support for unpaid users i think

Comment: I believe they do have support for unpaid users. And just because the boxes are separate doesn't mean all is well. If one box is situated completely inside another box it is most probably "attached" to the box, so if the outer box is hidden, the inner box will not show no matter what you do.

Answer (score 0):

instead of boxes, use multi-state boxes available in the boxes tab between elements. So you can edit by placing the elements in each state without having to hide them.

In the code:

```
$w("#myStatebox").changeState("state2");
```

Instead of

```
$w('#box1').hide()
$w('#box2').show()
$w('#text12').show()
```

You can also add a button, create a click event and put the command to change state inside the event, it would look like this:

```
$w("#button1").onClick( (event) => {
  $w("#myStatebox").changeState("state2");
} );

$w("#button2").onClick( (event) => {
  $w("#myStatebox").changeState("state3");
} ); 

//$w("#button3").onClick...
```